# JavaScript - Default values of file inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file

In my app, users can fill a form (all kinds of inputs, including file inputs). At any point and after posting that form to backend, they can edit the form. In that case, the text/selects/numbers... are set to the value entered by the user previously.

What would the best practice be for file inputs ? I know I can't "preload" them for security reasons.

These files are stored on the backend. I need to find a way to figure out :

- If the user hasn't changed the file
- If the user has changed the file
- If the user wants to remove the existing file (if possible ?)

Comment: You will only be able to differentiate between two cases - did they send a file, or did they not send a file. If you want to figure out whether they might have uploaded "the same" file again (assuming that means "same" regarding file content, not name/date), you will need to compare their new upload, to the previously stored one. And if you don't want to delete their existing file, every time the submit the form with _no_ file selected - then you will have to handle deletion separately.

Comment: You could do something like compute a checksum on the client via the file API. When you load the form, the server can send the current checksum in the database. If the user provides a file and the checksum is the same, you can disable the `<input>` and it won't be posted with the form.

Comment: It's quite unclear if it has to work even after page reload. Could you please clarify this point?

Comment: After page reload ? On mount, my component calls for the data of that specific form and fills the inputs accordingly. On send, a new "form" item is made in my database (i need to keep the previous ones due to GDPR)

@Pointy, an equal checksum would mean the user has sent the same file then. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Pointy just checking the `.lastModified` should be enough in 99.9% of the cases and is way less computationally heavy.

Comment: @Kaiido sure, it just depends on how much you're willing to trust the client clock. If the form is uploading a 2GB file, it's going to take a long time anyway :)

Comment: So my back has to sent the lastModified, got it. If the client doesn't send a file, the field will be undefined, therefore my back has to reuse the previous file in that case.

Comment: The .lastModified field is taken from the metadata built by the OS, it represents the last time the file has been modified on disk, with a 1ms precision. So sure you could have two files modified at the same ms, with the same file name and size? That would be the 0.1% chance (which I think is actually less) ;-P. The greatest risk would be that users could overwrite the File interface, but I don't think we're trying to prevent such cases. And yes @GuillaumeBB sending that to the server and getting it back should be a good compromise.